# MS Access: Highlight specific field in MS Access Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have some reports in MS Access which I use to check if data is missing in fields.This works fine,what I would like to have in order to have a better view of the missing fields is to highlight this fields by coloring them red.

Is this possible in MS Access?

Br,

Comment: You can use conditional formatting, in the Format menu.

Comment: Yes,thank you..seams to be right .But how can I set it up so that he checks for ,,Is Null'' fields , because the options he gives me ,are ,,is greater then..'' equal to'' etc. ..

Comment: Use `Expression Is` instead of `Field value is `. Then you can enter an expression like `myField is null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting, in the Format menu.
Use `Expression Is` instead of `Field value is` . Then you can enter an expression like `myField is null`.

Comment: Yes,thank you ,this worked. Just fyi the correct expression is : IsNull([FieldName])